# Assert every key of object to be an array

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I have an object as below structure for API response.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Successfully fetch all items!",
    "data": {
        "services": [
            {
                "id": "E",
                "name": null,
                "price": 50,
                "discount_per": 2
            }
        ],
        "combos": [
            {
                "id": "w",
                "name": "3 Times Oil change, 4 Itmes Car Wash",
                "price": 5000,
                "discount_per": 10,
                "start_date": null,
                "expiry_date": "2020-02-04T12:00:00.000Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to write a unit test for this structure.
Here, if there is no data, data will be `{}`.

keys `services` and `combos` won't be there if no data is inside them, also they will be array of object always

This is what I tried.

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
const request = require('supertest')
const _ = require('lodash')

const app = require('../../src/app')


describe('GET /api/v1/items', function () {
    it('OK, Got items successfully', async () => {
        const result = await request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/items')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
        expect(result)
            .to.be.a('Object')
        expect(result.body.status, "status should be a boolean and true")
            .to.be.a('Boolean').true
        expect(result.body.data, "data should be an Object and every key should an Array")
            .to.satisfy(data => {
                if(!_.isEmpty(data)) {
                    expect(data).to.have.any.keys('services', 'combos')  
                    _.forOwn(data, (value, key) => {
                        expect(data[key]).to.be.a('Array')
                     })
                }
            })   
    })
})
```

But I am getting below error.

> 1) GET /api/v1/items
>          OK, Got items successfully:
>        AssertionError: data should be an Object and every key should an Array: expected { Object (services, combos) } to satisfy [Function]
>         at Context. (test\items\getAllItems.js:20:17)
>         at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was silly mistake I didn't notice. I wasn't returning anything from satisfy funciton.

```
describe('GET /api/v1/items', function () {
    it('OK, Got items successfully', async () => {
        const result = await request(app)
            .get('/api/v1/items')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
        expect(result)
            .to.be.a('Object')
        expect(result.body.status, "status should be a boolean and true")
            .to.be.a('Boolean').true
        expect(result.body.data, "data should be an Object and every key should an Array")
            .to.satisfy(data => {
                expect(data).to.be.a('Object')
                if(!_.isEmpty(data)) {
                    expect(data).to.have.any.keys('services', 'combos')  
                    _.forOwn(data, (value, key) => {
                        expect(data[key]).to.be.a('Array')
                     })
                    return true
                }
                return true
            })   
    })
})
```